# GUI thread move() method misbehaving

Tags: java, swing

**EDIT**
**: it seems that in my `move()` method, java has to skip one of the 2 if statements**

Keeping it simple. I'm trying to make a GUI in java that models the following `class Truck` behavior: the blue squares are supposed to run up their diagonales, which they do. But when they are supposed to bounce back once they reach the edge point of the square they just fly away. I've placed a condition to prevent this, but it never passes. I'll upload GUI and Drawable, but I don't think they are needed.

[image]

Class Truck:

```
package construction_site;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.plaf.ButtonUI;

public class Truck extends Thread implements Drawable {

    private boolean isFull = false;
    private int x, y;
    private int capacity;
    private Panel panel;
    static int r = 20;
    private int dx, dy;
    private Site site;
    private Building building;

    public Truck(int x, int y, Panel panel, Building building, Site site) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.building = building;
        this.panel = panel;
        this.site = site;
        this.start();
    }

    public void setCapacity(int capacity) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();

        while (true) {
            move();
            panel.repaint();

            try {
                sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setDirection(int i) {

        if (i == 0) {
            dx = -1;
            dy = -1;
        }

        if (i == 1) {
            dx = 1;
            dy = -1;
        }

        if (i == 2) {
            dx = -1;
            dy = 1;

        }

        if (i == 3) {
            dx = 1;
            dy = 1;

        }

    }

    private void move() {

        if (site.truckOnSite(x, y)) {
            site.loadTruck(this);
            dx *= -1;
            dy *= -1;
        }

        if (building.containsTruck(this)) {
            building.unloadTruck(this);
            dx *= -1;
            dy *= -1;
        }

        x += dx;
        y += dy;

    }

    public int getDx() {
        return dx;
    }

    public void setFull(boolean isFull) {
        this.isFull = isFull;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        if (isFull)
            g.fillRect(x - 10, y - 10, r, r);
        else
            g.drawRect(x - 10, y - 10, r, r);
    }

}
```

Class Panel:

```
package construction_site;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Panel extends JPanel {

    private ArrayList<Drawable> drawables = new ArrayList<>();
    private Site site;
    private Building[] buildings = new Building[4];
    private Truck[] trucks = new Truck[4];
    private Van[] vans = new Van[4];

    public Panel(int w, int h) {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(w, h));

        site = new Site(100, 75, 500, 500, this);
        drawables.add(site);

        buildings[0] = new Building(100, 75, this);
        buildings[1] = new Building(100 + 500, 75, this);
        buildings[2] = new Building(100, 75 + 500, this);
        buildings[3] = new Building(100 + 500, 75 + 500, this);

        for (Building b : buildings) 
            drawables.add(b);

        trucks[0] = new Truck(100 + 250, 75 + 250, this, buildings[0], site);
        trucks[1] = new Truck(100 + 250, 75 + 250, this, buildings[1], site);
        trucks[2] = new Truck(100 + 250, 75 + 250, this, buildings[2], site);
        trucks[3] = new Truck(100 + 250, 75 + 250, this, buildings[3], site);

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            trucks[i].setDirection(i);

        for (Truck t : trucks)
            drawables.add(t);

    }


    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        for (Drawable d : drawables)
            d.draw(g);
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
            g.drawLine(buildings[0].getX(), buildings[0].getY(), buildings[i].getX(), buildings[i].getY());
        g.drawLine(buildings[1].getX(), buildings[1].getY(), buildings[2].getX(), buildings[2].getY());
    }

}
```

Class Building:

```
package construction_site;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class Building extends Thread implements Drawable {

    private Panel panel;
    private boolean done = false;
    private int x, y;
    static int w = 100;
    static int h = 100;
    private ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private Condition insufficientMaterial = lock.newCondition();
    private Condition insufficientMisc = lock.newCondition();
    private Condition sufficient = lock.newCondition();
    private int material = 0;
    private int misc = 0;
    private int spent = 0;

    public Building(int x, int y, Panel panel) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.panel = panel;
        this.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();

        lock.lock();

        while(material < 100 )
            try {
                insufficientMaterial.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        spent += 150;
        misc -= 50;
        material -= 100;

        try {
            sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void unloadVan(Van v) {

        lock.lock();
        System.out.println("Truck got in");

        if (material >= 100 && misc >=50) {

        }
        misc += 50;
        v.setCapacity(0);

        insufficientMisc.signalAll();
        lock.unlock();

    }

    public void unloadTruck(Truck t) {

        lock.lock();


        material += 10000;
        t.setCapacity(0);
        t.setFull(false);

        insufficientMaterial.signalAll();
        lock.unlock();
    }


    public void setMaterial(int material) {
        this.material = material;
    }

    public void setMisc(int misc) {
        this.misc = misc;
    }


    public boolean containsVan(int x2, int y2) {
        return ( Math.sqrt((x - x2)*(x - x2) + (y - y2)*(y - y2)) <= h/2 );
    }

    public boolean containsTruck(Truck t) {
        return (x == t.getX() && y == t.getY());
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }


    @Override
    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawRect(x - 50, y - 50, 100, 100);
    }

}
```

Class Site:

```
package construction_site;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Site implements Drawable {

    private int x, y, w, h;
    private Panel panel;

    public Site(int x, int y, int w, int h, Panel panel) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.w = w;
        this.h = h;
        this.panel = panel;
    }

    public boolean contains(int x2, int y2) {
        return (x == x2 && y == 2);
    }

    public boolean truckOnSite(int x2, int y2) {
        return ( x2 == x + w / 2 && y2 == y + h / 2);
    }

    public boolean vanOnSite(int x2, int y2) {
        return ( (x2 == x && y2 == y + h / 2) || (x2 == x + w && y2 == y + h / 2) );
    }

    public void loadVan(Van v) {
        v.setCapacity(5000);
    }

    public void loadTruck(Truck t) {
        t.setCapacity(10000);
        t.setFull(true);
    }


    @Override
    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        g.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
    }


}
```

Comment: It would have been more helpful had you provided a [complete runnable example which demonstrated your problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), looked like an interesting problem

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out much later, it doesn't seem truncation errors were the problem at hand. It was a mistake at setting the trucks' starting point and the condition that decides when they're supposed to turn the other way. What looked like the truck bouncing off, was actually the oppsoite truck from the same diagonal passing through. A simple change in direction of my `Truck`'s `move()` method did the trick.

```
public void setDirection(int i) {

    if (i == 0) {
        dx = -1;
        dy = -1;
    }

    if (i == 1) {
        dx = 1;
        dy = -1;
    }

    if (i == 2) {
        dx = -1;
        dy = 1;

    }

    if (i == 3) {
        dx = 1;
        dy = 1;

    }

}
```